# Alpine image in gitlab CI: find does not replace {}

Tags: find, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I have the following script setup in my gitlab ci:

> find . -iname "*.tf" -exec envsubst < {} ;

However, I get an error message "/bin/sh: eval: line 119: can't open {}: no such file".
I also tried putting single quotes around {}, but got the same error. Maybe I did not understand find correctly? Does the shell syntax in Alpine ash differ from standard sh or bash and it does not work because of that?

Answer (score 0):

the redirection `<` applies to find and not to envsubst as you're expecting

Comment: Wow, would probably have never figured that out... Do you know the correct syntax?